# Adding anchor tags to components in webform module (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

Does anyone know how to add links to components within the webform module of Drupal?
eg.

```
            module 1 module 2 module 3
<a>row1</a>  (cbox)   (cbox)  (cbox)
```

Comment: Could you add and ID attr to each field you need to anchor to?

Answer (score 1):

There is a template for webform - webform-form-[nid].tpl.php (where nid is the Node ID of the webform you want to customize). This is where you would start creating a custom form. The exact process depends on how you created your webform, but judicious use of the Devel module and your browser developer tools will help you find the specific pieces that need to be modified.